# jQuery Mobile Toggle fires but is not allowed to

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, toggle

I want to rebuild an existing menu(navigation) for better mobile performance.
When the user first clicks the menu it fades in but when the user clicks a link which have a sub-menu the whole menu fades out(toggle is fired). But instead the sub-menu should fadeIn

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="menu-menue-1-container"><ul class="menu" id="menu-menue-1"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-140" id="menu-item-140"  >
<a href="">Startseite</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-144" id="menu-item-144"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/shop/">Shop</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-253" id="menu-item-253"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/produkt-kategorie/tabak-taschen/">Tabak Taschen</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-143" id="menu-item-143"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/produkt-kategorie/ohrringe/">Accessoires</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-254" id="menu-item-254"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/produkt-kategorie/ohrringe/">Ohrringe</a>
</li>

</ul>

</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-product menu-item-has-children menu-item-141" id="menu-item-141"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/shop/hoodie-bp/hoodiebpbasic/">Hoodie Backpack</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-product menu-item-250" id="menu-item-250"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/shop/hoodie-bp/hoodiebpbasic/">Hoodie BP BASIC</a>
</li>

</ul>

</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-142" id="menu-item-142"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/produkt-kategorie/tabak-taschen/">Tabaktaschen</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-162" id="menu-item-162"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/warenkorb/">Warenkorb</a>
</li>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-251" id="menu-item-251"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/category/news/">News</a>

<ul class="sub-menu">

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-252" id="menu-item-252"  >
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/staging/helloworld/">HelloWorld</a>
</li>

</ul>

</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu-menue-1 {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 48px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    padding-top: 58px;
    background-image: url('../images/nav_active.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu-menue-1 li {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.sub-menu{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery/Javascript:

```
(function(a) {
        (jQuery.browser = jQuery.browser || {}).mobile = /(android|ipad|playbook|silk|android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))
    })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);

    console.log('Mobiles Gerät: ' + jQuery.browser.mobile);

    $("#menu-menue-1").bind(jQuery.browser.mobile ? 'click' : 'tap', function() {


        $(this).find('li').fadeToggle(500);

        if (jQuery.browser.mobile === true) {

            console.log('mobile!');


        } else {

            console.log('desktop!');

            $(".menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
                $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle(500);
            });

        }

    });
    $(".menu-item-has-children").bind('tap', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('bis hierhin!');
        $(this).find('.sub-menu').toggle(1);
    });
```

So What am I doing wrong? thx in advance and sorry for my bad englisch.

Comment: are you using jQuery-Mobile framework?

Comment: yep, like the title says ;)

Comment: title says so, but html/js show no sign of jQM usage ;)

Comment: the "tap" event ;) but i dont think its a problem of jQuery Mobile